# jQuery add/remove/toggle classes to non-parent div from radio selection

Tags: jquery, radio-button, toggle, addclass, removeclass

Having some trouble with trying to dynamically add and remove classes to a div based on radio selection. Essentially, I'm attempting to have a second header area that can be dynamically changed based on radio selections.

The HTML:

```
<!-- Headers -->

<div class="header">
    <p>I'm a header</p>
</div>
<div class="extra-header header-hidden">
    <p>I'm an extra header</p>
</div>

<!-- Radio Buttons -->

<div class="radio-inline">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="headerChoice" class="trigger" id="headerOptionActivate" value="activate" checked />
          Off
    </label>
</div>
<div class="radio-inline">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="headerChoice" class="trigger" id="headerOptionSmall" value="small"  />
          s
    </label>
</div>
<div class="radio-inline">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="headerChoice" class="trigger" id="headerOptionMedium" value="medium" />
          m
    </label>
</div>
<div class="selection-wrap">
    <div class="radio-inline">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="headerChoice" class="trigger" id="headerOptionLarge" value="large" />
          L
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Javascript (using jQuery)

```
$('.trigger').change(function(){
    $('.extra-header').removeClass('header-hidden');
    $('.extra-header').toggleClass('header-' + $(this).val());
});
```

Here's a fiddle of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/A3zeS/1/

As you can see, the classes are currently being added, they're just not being removed. I've tried numerous variations of jquery but haven't been able to figure it out. Much obliged for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for something like this

```
$('.trigger').on('change', function () {
    $('.extra-header').toggleClass('header-hidden', $('#headerOptionActivate').is(':checked'));

    $('.trigger').each(function() {
        $('.extra-header').toggleClass('header-' + this.value, this.checked);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/A3zeS/4/)

Comment: @A.Wolff - Thank's, I was busy in jsFiddle, didn't see everyone else posting, and haven't had time to test the other answers, but at first glance it doesn't look like they remove the header when "off" is checked ?

Comment: Many thanks... incredible how quickly such helpful answers come! This did the trick. I'm new to javascript/jQuery and didn't realize I needed to use a `.each` function.  


In attempts to understand exactly what's going on here, why a call to both `this.value` and `this.checked`? Is `this.checked` referencing another class or is it modifying the `('header-' + this.value`?


Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use following snippet:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A3zeS/5/)

```
$('.trigger').change(function () {
    var self = this;
    $('.extra-header').toggleClass(function (_, c) {
        return c.match(/ header-\w+/)[0] + ' header-' + (self.value !== "activate" ? self.value:"hidden")
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the other classes are static and won't change then

```
$('.trigger').change(function () {
    $('.extra-header').removeClass('header-hidden');
    $('.extra-header').removeClass().addClass('extra-header header-' + $(this).val());
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bcKRu/)

else

```
$('.trigger').change(function () {
    var self = this;
    $('.extra-header').removeClass('header-hidden').attr('class', function (i, clazz) {
        return clazz.replace(/header-[^\s]+/g, '') + ' header-' + self.value;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('.extra-header').removeClass().addClass('extra-header').addClass('header-' + $(this).val())
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/A3zeS/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/LRzLu/)